# How to remove shipping options from shopping cart based on which products are in the cart and what shipping options are linked to these products

Tags: php, arrays, logic, e-commerce

I have a marketplace where sellers can sell multiple products and specify shipping options separately, linking the shipping options to the products in a many-to-many relationship.

In the shopping cart controller, I'm trying to remove shipping options intelligently so that sellers aren't left with too little money for shipping costs.

As an example, consider a shopping cart with two products in it. The seller has chosen one shipping option per product:

```
$products = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Lightweight widget',
        'shipping_option_ids' => array(
            1
        )
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Heavyweight widget',
        'shipping_option_ids' => array(
            2
        )
    )
);
```

These are the two shipping options:

```
$shipping_options = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Cheap shipping option',
        'price' => 100
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Expensive shipping option',
        'price' => 200
    )
);
```

So, we have two products, each linked to a different shipping option. Using the expensive shipping option, both products can be shipped in the same package.

Now, I need to remove the cheap shipping option from the shipping options array. This will leave the customer with only one choice of shipping option – the expensive one.

## Generalization

### Conditions

- Two or more products in the shopping cart that don't have at least one shipping option in common.

  ### Action
- Remove all the shipping options except those linked to the product with the most expensive shipping options.

Comment: So, can you have more than one shipping option linked to one product? And what do you mean for "the most expensive shipping options"? Is it sum of prices for all shipping options for product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem the following way:

```
// Prepare for removal procedure
foreach ($store['shipping_options'] as &$shipping_option)
{
    $shipping_option['removal_candidate'] = FALSE;
}
unset($shipping_option);

// Label shipping options that aren't linked to all products:
foreach ($products as $product)
{
    if (!in_array($shipping_option['id'], $product['shipping_option_ids']))
    {
        $shipping_option['removal_candidate'] = TRUE;
    }
}

$number_of_shipping_options = count($shipping_options);

// Loop through each shipping option:
for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_shipping_options; $i++)
{
    $shipping_option_a = $shipping_options[$i];

    // Compare each shipping option with each of the other shipping options:
    foreach ($shipping_options as $key => $shipping_option_b)
    {
        // Compare different shipping options only:
        if ($shipping_option_a['id'] != $shipping_option_b['id'])
        {
            // Remove the shipping option with the lowest price:
            if ($shipping_option_a['price'] < $shipping_option_b['price'])
            {
                if ($shipping_option_a['removal_candidate'])
                {
                    unset($store['shipping_options'][$i]);
                    $shipping_options_removed = TRUE;
                    $number_of_shipping_options = count($store['shipping_options']);
                }
                elseif ($shipping_option_a['price'] > $shipping_option_b['price'])
                {
                    if ($shipping_option_b['removal_candidate'])
                    {
                        unset($store['shipping_options'][$key]);
                        $shipping_options_removed = TRUE;
                        $number_of_shipping_options = count($store['shipping_options']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Refresh key numbers:
    $store['shipping_options'] = array_values($store['shipping_options']);
}
```